# Is the javafx tag deprecated for javafx-2 and javafx-8?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I don't know if this is the best place to ask such a question,
I see some `JavaFX` guys here, **retag** some questions by replacing the [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) by [javafx-2](/questions/tagged/javafx-2) and adopting the new [javafx-8](/questions/tagged/javafx-8). Is it deprecated or what?

**Edit**: 
don't tag your question with [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) tag, unless it is related to `JavaFX 1`.

From the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info):

> "javafx" tag is mostly dedicated for JavaFX 1.3 and older

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Stack Overflow itself belong on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) for `JavaFX` 1 ... 1.3 technology, which used special javafx script language.
- [javafx-2](/questions/tagged/javafx-2) for questions about `JavaFX` 2... 2.2.*+ versions.
- [javafx-8](/questions/tagged/javafx-8) about JavaFX 8, which will be published in 2014 as part of `JDK8`.

JavaFX 8 - is the same JavaFX 2 teachnology, but is the next version, and contains tons of fixes and features comparing to 2.*+ versions.

So, none of them is deprecated. Just use proper tag for proper version.

You can notice, that you have access to JavaFX 8 with JDK early access releases of JDK : https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

And, I have to notice, that some fixes, done in JFX8 after 2.2GA release are backported to JavaFX 2.2.*, and some are not, so, it could be right, not to mix versions.